# How to convert a website to a apk?

Tags: android, program-entry-point

I was trying to convert a website to an app and after typing when I run the app in the emulator and real device the app close and says "the app has stopped working". This is the code of the Main Activity

And when I type webview in `mywebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView)` it says webview near the id is not specified. This is the code of the Main Activity.

```
    package com.example.darkslorde.supercell;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://forum.supercell.com");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is            present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your layout.xml file

Comment: Check your logcat for what the error is

Comment: i  solved it thx

Comment: it was a problem in structure

Answer (score -1):

You can use a tool **website to apk generator** This app don't need any extra SDK or anything and its size is less then 15MB.[Its easy and very sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvpEa.png). If you want to download
 [click here](https://websitetoapk.com/index.html)